# What's the best way to test an element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, dom

There are a couple of ways I could do this (That I'm aware of).

Test css display

```
if ($('#foo').css('display') == 'none')
```

Test the visibility

```
if ($('#foo').is(':visible'))
```

In the visibility I can check if the element is there.

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible,
>   since they still consume space in the layout.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

But, note that in both I can't test the visibility (by the user) because:

> Hiding an element can be done by setting the display property to
>   "none" or the visibility property to "hidden". However, notice that
>   these two methods produce different results:
>
> **visibility:** hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same
>   space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the
>   layout.
>
> **display:** none hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The
>   element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the
>   element is not there:

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

So in neither of the examples I test if the element is visible in all senses for the user.

So my question is:

- **What're the differences between the two if's codes from above?**
- **What's the best way to test if an element is visible to the user:**

Should I have to use something like:

```
if ($('#foo').is(':visible') && 
    $('#foo').css('opacity') > 0 && 
    $('#foo').css('visibility') != 'hidden')
```

Comment: Have you tried that last block of code to see if it works?

Comment: **1.** What's the best way to test if an element is visible to the user? >> `$('#foo').is(':visible')` is the best way to check if the element is visible to the user(meaning displayed) **2.** What're the differences between the two if's codes from above? >> You have quoted the difference between, `visible` and `display`. So now, what is your question?

Comment: What about an element that's perfectly visible but has another element positioned on top of it through `z-index`? What if this topmost div has an opaque background? Or a transparent one? Or a *partially* transparent one? Is the element "below" considered visible?

Comment: How about just looking at your screen and see if you can spot the element yourself. Never trust users, they know nothing ?

Comment: @Vega and others as well I made a comment in +Caleb answer that explain most of this comments in my question, [take a look at my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589810/whats-the-best-way-to-test-an-element-in-the-dom/10590544#comment13717265_10590004) I hope this will make things clear and we all can get the best result of this. Thanks in advance for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to implement a custom function like below and test/improve as new things come up,

```
$.fn.isReallyVisible = function () { //rename function name as you like..
    return (this.css('display') != 'none' &&
            this.css('visibility') != 'hidden' &&
            this.css('opacity') > 0);
}
```

The above should be cross browser proof as we are using jQuery `.css` function (specifically for opacity).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/PpCuA/1/)

Comment: Really good. Just wondering, you are using `this.css('display') != 'none'` over `$('#foo').is(':visible')`. Can you tell me why this choice ?

Comment: @MichelAyres Just a minor improvement. `is` is jQuery function which can different types of arguments and `:visible` is one of them.. Internally it will filter first that it is `:visible` and execute its corresponding flow and In the end it will be doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that being hidden using "visible" attribute leaves the element on the page, just not actually displayed.  So, it's spacing will be taken into account when the page renders the rest of the display.

It seems that doing it the other way actually stops the element from being put onto the page, which can change how other elements on the page are laid out.

usually testing the visible part is enough from my experience, but if you are wanting to be more complete, then yeah you would have to check using "&&" conditions on multiple attributes.
It really all depends on how clean the code you are using is, and how well tested the rest of the UI aspect of the system is.

The other thing to consider is what is the purpose of the test.  Are you testing code that you wrote, or how the browser is using Javascript to render the page?  You want to be testing the code that you are creating, and rely on the fact that the browser works (because if the browser stops working, then the whole thing is unreliable anyway).  So if your code tells the element to set some attribute, then checking for that attribute is all the testing you need to do.  Anything on top of that can only really be proven by testing outside of the code itself (as in manualy looking at the page and other things like that).

Comment: My concern is more about the cross-browser and performance. Also if there is something I'm missing in my logic. This is why I wish someone to explain to me the differences and best way of doing this. if you look at SO you can see lot's of different answer about the "Find waldo in my dom" type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if an element exists in the DOM you could just do this:

```
$.fn.exists = function () {
    return this.length > 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
$('#myid').exists();
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but this would not take more time than the two above(in the question)? or they are alias one of the other?

Comment: @FelixKling He is using `this.length > 0` I didn't understood your comment (he only add the call for the js function in his edit)

Comment: Well it doesn't base the existence of an element on the display property, it returns whether or not it actually exists.

Comment: @Michel: When I commented it was `$(this).length > 1`. Gabe probably edited within the 5 min grace periode. Otherwise, why would I have commented?

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't knew about this 5min spam. I just checked the edit and didn't saw any subject about it, so I asked why to understand the meaning behind it. Thanks for the explanation about the edit without show. Usually when I edit my questions/answers with short time it recorded in the log. Never noticed that.

Comment: @Michel: No worries :) Yeah, in the first 5 minutes, the changes are not recorded...